# HTML5 progress tag in WebKit not working?

Tags: html, safari, webview, progress

I need to display operation system native progress bar in (html5) web page.
I have progress tag in following html file

< progress value="22" max="100" />

It works great in Safari 6.0 OSX Lion 10.7.4, but it doesn't in WebKit's WebView.. 
The rest of the page displaying is well, but no progress bar.
Anyone have idea why this is happening? 
I thought WebKit and Safari is actually the same, but it seems it doesn't. :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [CanIUse#Progress](http://caniuse.com/#feat=progressmeter).

---

This works in Firefox 14, Chrome 21 and Safari etc.

```
<progress value="22" max="100" />
```

But as you can see from CanIUse android browser does not yet support the progress element.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I've seen this.

Safari 6.0 on my Mac OS X supports it well, as I said. But at the same moment the WebKit, which is on the same Mac OS X, doesn't. I'm guessing why, because Safari is supposed to be using that same WebKit framework on that same OSX.

Comment: After some investigation I've found that Safari doen't link with /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework. Instead it links with /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Safari.framework. And the user agent of Safari is AppleWebKit/536.25 and WebKit's is AppleWebKit/534.56.5. I think that means that Safari simply doesn't use the WebKit which I'm trying to call to display HTML5 progress tag. :( sad

Answer (score 0):

I think the progress tag need to close. Please try this

```
<progress value="22" max="100"></progress>
```

It may help you